Proving path connectedness of a set
Let $K$ be a compact convex set with nonempty interior. Let $y\in \partial K$. Suppose there exists a ball $B_\delta(y)$ such that $\partial B_\delta(y)\cap K$ is connected. I want to argue that $B_\delta(y)\setminus K$ is connected.
My attempt: Draw a tangent plane to $K$ at $y$. The part of $B_\delta(y)$ that is above the tangent plane (shaded in red) is convex so it is a connected subset of $B_\delta(y)\setminus K$. I want to show any point in $B_\delta(y)\setminus K$ below the tangent plane (shaded in yellow) is path connected to the connected subset. But I don't know how to show it and I'm stuck. Are there better ways? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Update: My latest thoughts are: For any point in the interior of the yellow region, i.e the interior points of $B_\delta(y_0)\setminus K$ that are strictly below the tangent plane can be connected to the tangent plane by drawing a perpendicular path to the tangent plane. Each of these paths will lie entirely in the interior of the yellow region because (i) moving toward the tangent plane means moving away from $K$ (ii) its distance from $y_0$ is less than the radius $\delta$ so it it in the interior of $B_{\delta}(y_0)$. Thus, it is connected to the convex set (the red region). Therefore, the set in question is connected. Does this argument work?

Reread the hint I gave you on the previous post.

Yes, your hint led me to this line of thinking. Am I on the right track? From what I can see  part of the ball above the tangent plane is convex so it is already connected, no? So my reasoning is to show the rest of the part can be connected to that set.

I said above the graph of the function, not above the tangent plane. :)

@TedShifrin Does the argument in the update work?
